# web browser local storage return value is null but it's not shown as a null value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, null, local-storage

[image]

Here's my local storage key-value pair

ProductsInCart : null

when I access it in JavaScript in flowing line,

```
let cartItemsList = localStorage.getItem("ProductsInCart");
            console.log(cartItemsList)
```

cartItemsList value is null,

But when I check it with the following condition,

```
if (cartItemsList != null) {
                
                console.log('not null')
            } else {
                console.log('null')
            }
```

the out put is not null,

Here is my original JavaScript code ,

```
 var imgSrc = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storedSingleProductImage'))
        MainImg.src = imgSrc;

        var sProductCategory = document.querySelector('#productCategory')
        var sProductName = document.querySelector('#productName')
        var sProductPrice = document.querySelector('#productPrice')
        var sNumberOfproducts = document.querySelector('#numberOfproducts');

        let sProdCategory = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storedSingleProductCategory'))
        let sProdName = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storedSingleProductName'))
        let sProdPrice = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storedSingleItemPrice'))

        sProductCategory.innerHTML = sProdCategory
        sProductName.innerHTML = sProdName
        sProductPrice.innerHTML = sProdPrice
        let sNumberOfprod =1;
        sNumberOfproducts.addEventListener('input', () => {
             sNumberOfprod = sNumberOfproducts.value;
        });
        function addToCart() {

            let cartItemsList = localStorage.getItem("ProductsInCart");
            console.log(cartItemsList)

            let cartItems = [];
            //this condition true for null values also
            if(cartItemsList !== null){

                //I want parse a not null value for the JSON.parse() because it will pop a error otherwise
                 cartItems =  JSON.parse(cartItemsList);
            }
  
            cartItems.push(
                {
                    sProdCategory,
                    sProdName,
                    sProdPrice,
                    sNumberOfprod,
                    imgSrc
                }
            )
            localStorage.setItem("ProductsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
            alert(`${sNumberOfprod} items of ${sProdName}-(${sProdCategory}) added to the cart.`)
        }
```

this the out put of the code

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')
    at addToCart (sproduct.html:154:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (sproduct.html:54:58)
```

Comment: personally I would just do `const cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ProductsInCart")) || [];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage.setItem` saves value as `stringified` for non string values. You need to check the value against "null" or after `JSON.parse`.

Suggest always use the following wrapper utils to while using localStore

```
const getLocalStorageValue = (key, defaultValue = undefined) => {
  const strValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
  let value = defaultValue;
  if (strValue) {
    try {
      value = JSON.parse(strValue);
    } catch ({ message }) {
      // execption
      console.info("Caught error while JSON parse", message);
    }
  }
  return value;
};

const setLocalStorageValue = (key, value) => {
  try {
    const valueStr = JSON.stringify(value);
    localStorage.setItem(key, valueStr);
  } catch ({ message }) {
    // execption
    console.info("Caught error while JSON stringify", message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not parsed your JSON object before if condition Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) while get the data from localStorge.

```
let cartItemsList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ProductsInCart"));
let cartItems = [];
 //this condition true for null values also
if(cartItemsList !== null){
//I want parse a not null value for the JSON.parse() because it will pop a error otherwise
 cartItems =  JSON.parse(cartItemsList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In local storage all values are stored as String and hence when you get item it is returning:-

```
cartItemsList = "null" and not cartItemsList = null
```

So Either you remove double quotes from the string "null" before checking like this:-

```
 cartItemsList = cartItemsList.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
```

Or you check your condition as "null" like:-

```
if (cartItemsList != "null")
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set the items first and should check the localstorage in the console of the web browser.

```
localstorage.setItem("ProductsInCart");
console.log("localstorage");
```

Comment: Why would you do that?